# What is the best way to store an object that needs to exists for the lifetime of the application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In ASP.Net I would use Session state to store objects. Where would I store objects needed in SilverLight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't to store information on the client you can use isolated storage.

for example:

```
// Create an instance of IsolatedStorageSettings. 
private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 
// Add a key and its value. 
userSettings.Add("userImage", "BlueHills.jpg"); 
// Remove the setting. 
userSettings.Remove("userImage");
```

Look here it could get you started: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/